# Django Form: comma separated decimal numbers throwing validation errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have a form where user can enter decimal/integer values as comma separated like, 500,000 or 500,000.00. When I process the field using the Django ModelForm it raises the validation error like `Enter a number`, I want to remove those "," before the value makes into the DB.The `join_bonus` and `var_pay` fields have attribute `required=False` but still those fields raise 'This field is required.' validation error.

My Form:

```
class EmployeeSalaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Salary
        fields = [
            'basic_salary',
            'convyence_allowance',
            'medical_allowance',
            'mobile_allowance',
            'executive_allowance',
            'gross_salary',
            'epf',
            'health_benefit',
            'ctc',
            'join_bonus',
            'var_pay',
        ]

        
        basic_salary = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        convyence_allowance = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        medical_allowance = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        mobile_allowance = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        executive_allowance = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        gross_salary = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        epf = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        health_benefit = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        ctc = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2)
        join_bonus = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2, required=False)
        var_pay = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=11,decimal_places=2, required=False)
        

        def clean_basic_salary(self):
            basic_salary = self.cleaned_data['basic_salary']

            return basic_salary.replace(',', '')

        def clean_convyence_allowance(self):
            convyence_allowance = self.cleaned_data['convyence_allowance']

            return convyence_allowance.replace(',', '')

        def clean_medical_allowance(self):
            medical_allowance = self.cleaned_data['medical_allowance']

            return medical_allowance.replace(',', '')

        def clean_mobile_allowance(self):
            mobile_allowance = self.cleaned_data['mobile_allowance']

            return mobile_allowance.replace(',', '')

        def clean_executive_allowance(self):
            executive_allowance = self.cleaned_data['executive_allowance']

            return executive_allowance.replace(',', '')

        def clean_gross_salary(self):
            gross_salary = self.cleaned_data['gross_salary']

            return gross_salary.replace(',', '')

        def clean_epf(self):
            epf = self.cleaned_data['epf']

            return epf.replace(',', '')

        def clean_health_benefit(self):
            health_benefit = self.cleaned_data['health_benefit']

            return health_benefit.replace(',', '')

        def clean_ctc(self):
            ctc = self.cleaned_data['ctc']

            return ctc.replace(',', '')

        def clean_join_bonus(self):
            join_bonus = self.cleaned_data['join_bonus']

            return 0 if join_bonus == None else join_bonus.replace(',', '')

        def clean_var_pay(self):
            var_pay = self.cleaned_data['var_pay']

            return 0 if var_pay == None else var_pay.replace(',', '')
```

**Salary Model:**

```
class Salary(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'emp_salary_master'

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    basic_salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    hra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    convyence_allowance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    medical_allowance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    mobile_allowance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    executive_allowance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    gross_salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    epf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    health_benefit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    
    ctc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    
    join_bonus = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    
    var_pay = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    
    to_date = models.DateField()

    from_date = models.DateField()

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing type casting:

```py
def clean_basic_salary(self):
    basic_salary = self.cleaned_data['basic_salary']

    return int(basic_salary.replace(',', ''))

def clean_convyence_allowance(self):
    convyence_allowance = self.cleaned_data['convyence_allowance']

    return int(convyence_allowance.replace(',', ''))

def clean_medical_allowance(self):
    medical_allowance = self.cleaned_data['medical_allowance']

    return int(medical_allowance.replace(',', ''))

def clean_mobile_allowance(self):
    mobile_allowance = self.cleaned_data['mobile_allowance']

    return int(mobile_allowance.replace(',', ''))

def clean_executive_allowance(self):
    executive_allowance = self.cleaned_data['executive_allowance']

    return int(executive_allowance.replace(',', ''))

def clean_gross_salary(self):
    gross_salary = self.cleaned_data['gross_salary']

    return int(gross_salary.replace(',', ''))

def clean_epf(self):
    epf = self.cleaned_data['epf']

    return int(epf.replace(',', ''))

def clean_health_benefit(self):
    health_benefit = self.cleaned_data['health_benefit']

    return int(health_benefit.replace(',', ''))

def clean_ctc(self):
    ctc = self.cleaned_data['ctc']

    return int(ctc.replace(',', ''))

def clean_join_bonus(self):
    join_bonus = self.cleaned_data['join_bonus']

    return 0 if join_bonus == None else int(join_bonus.replace(',', ''))

def clean_var_pay(self):
    var_pay = self.cleaned_data['var_pay']

    return 0 if var_pay == None else int(var_pay.replace(',', ''))
```

As u have created these fields as a Decimal Field you can only input int or float values. When you get the data from a normal form it comes in the form of Strings. So either you have to use type casting or using Django Model forms to solve this issue. Hoping this would solve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your response but it will not work because those methods are run after the values are set. Since those fields expect a decimal value it will keep raising the validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old question, I would like to share my solution as follows

First create custom Decimal field

```
class CustomDecimalField(forms.DecimalField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return super().to_python(value.replace(',', ''))
```

Then use this CustomDecimalField in your form.